# Limit cache size from WebView on iOS app

Tags: objective-c, iphone, caching, webview, uiwebview

How can I limit cache size from WebView on iOS app?

Can I use one of these codes?

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:X];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:X];
```

Or is there a possibility to clear cache by clicking a button?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cache size with the following:

```
NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:MEMORY_CAPACITY
                                                     diskCapacity:DISK_CAPACITY
                                                         diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
```

Where MEMORY_CAPACITY and DISK_CAPACITY are NSUInteger values in bytes.